# Python 2.7.13 and Indigo

Tags: python, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a problem with running Python 2.7.13 with Indigo
Thanks,
Morpheus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250746/python-2.7.13-and-indigo/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2016-12-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-26**:
`.13` or `.23`? I assume `.13`?

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2016-12-26**:
Opps, Python 2.7.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It generally should work but is untested so you may run into an issue that needs to be worked around.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0